# is 対する an adverb in[ 彼女は質問に対する肯定とも否定ともとれる返事が上手い。]?

Tags: grammar

1. Is 対する an adverb in the sentence below?
2. If it's not an adverb, which noun of the sentence is it attached to, 肯定 or 否定 or 返事??

> Japanese: [彼女は質問に対する肯定とも否定ともとれる返事が上手い。]

> English: [She's really good at answering questions in a way where you can't tell if she's agreeing or
> disagreeing.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's a verb. https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%AF%BE%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/
2. 返事. If ような is added in this sentence, you may understand it easier such as 彼女は質問に対する肯定とも否定ともとれる(ような)返事が上手い。